# how to insert form value with the file upload option

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying this code but it is not working properly. without the file upload option in the form, the values are properly storing in the database but after the file upload option is added the values are not storing in databases and neither the uploaded file is stored in the upload folder. would you please help me

home_view.php

```
<style>
    div.error{
        color:black;
    }
</style>

<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php //echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css') ?>">
    <script src="<?php //echo base_url('assets/js/jquery.min.js') ?>"></script>
    <script src="<?php //echo base_url('assets/js/bootstrap.min.js') ?>"></script> -->


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Welcome to CodeIgniter</title>
    </head>

    <?php 
    if($this->session->flashdata("success")){ ?>


            <?php echo $this->session->flashdata("successfully submited your form"); 
            echo "</br>";

            ?>

        <?php
    }
    ?>

    <body >
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <hr>
                <h2 class="intro-text text-center">Contact
                <strong>Form</strong>
                </h2>
                <hr>
                <?php echo form_open_multipart('home/form_submission',array("method"=>"post")); ?>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo set_value('txt_name')?>" name="txt_name" placeholder="Full Name"   >

                            <?php echo form_error("txt_name","<div class='error'>","</div>"); echo "</br>" ?>

                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></span>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" value="<?php echo set_value('txt_email')?>" name="txt_email" placeholder="Email"   >

                            <?php echo form_error("txt_email","<div class='error'>","</div>"); echo "</br>" ?>

                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></span>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" value="<?php echo set_value('txt_password')?>" name="txt_password" placeholder="password"   >

                            <?php echo form_error("txt_password","<div class='error'>","</div>"); echo "</br>" ?>

                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1"><i class="fas fa-phone"></i></span>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" value="<?php echo set_value('txt_phone')?>" name="txt_phone" placeholder="Phone Number"  >

                            <?php echo form_error("txt_phone","<div class='error'>","</div>"); echo "</br>"?>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <textarea name="txt_message" cols="80" rows="6" class="form-control" value="<?php echo set_value('txt_message')?>" placeholder="Your Message" ></textarea>
                        </div>


                            <label> Choose file to upload here</label>

                            <input type="file" name="image_uploads" />



                        <button class="btn btn-lg" name="submit">Submit Your Message</button>
                    </div>
                <?php echo form_close(); ?> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

home.php

```
public function form_submission(){

        $this->form_validation->set_rules("txt_name","name", "required|min_length[6]|max_length[10]|is_unique[contact_form.name]");

        $this->form_validation->set_rules("txt_email","email", "required|is_unique[contact_form.email]");

        $this->form_validation->set_rules("txt_password","password", "required|is_unique[contact_form.password]");

        $this->form_validation->set_rules("txt_phone","phone", "required|is_unique[contact_form.phone]");

        $this->form_validation->set_rules("txt_message","message", "max_length[100]");


            if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE){

                $this->session->set_flashdata("error","failed to create user");
                $this->index();


            }
            else{

                $config["upload_path"]="./uploads";

            $config["allowed_types"]="jpg|png";

            $this->load->library("upload",$config);

            if($this->upload->do_upload()){ //file_upload in input type name attribute of form
                // file uploaded

                $this->upload->data();

            $data_array=array(
                "name" => $this->input->post("txt_name"),
                "email" => $this->input->post("txt_email"), 
                "password" =>  $this->input->post("txt_password"),
                "phone" =>  $this->input->post("txt_phone"),
                "message" =>  $this->input->post("txt_message")
                //"image" => $data["file_upload"]

            );

                    if ($this->form_model1->insert_into_table($data_array)){

                        $this->session->set_flashdata("success","Your form has been submitted successfully");

                        echo "success";

                        redirect('home/dashboard');
                } 
                else{
                    $this->session->set_flashdata("error","failed to create user");
                    $this->index();

                }


            }
            else{
                // //error
                // print_r($this->upload->display_errors()); // display_errors return all the errors while file uploading

                $errors = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                //$this->index();
                echo "error in uploading image";
            }



        }
    }


I expect to be inserted in the database but the actual result I am getting is "error in uploading image"
```

Answer (score 1):

TRT THIS EXAMPLE....

```
public function form_submission(){
    if($this->input->post('submit')){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("txt_name","name", "required|min_length[6]|max_length[10]|is_unique[contact_form.name]");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("txt_email","email", "required|is_unique[contact_form.email]");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("txt_password","password", "required|is_unique[contact_form.password]");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("txt_phone","phone", "required|is_unique[contact_form.phone]");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("txt_message","message", "max_length[100]");
    if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE){
        $this->session->set_flashdata("error","failed to create user");
        $this->index();

    }else{
        //Check whether user upload picture
        if(!empty($_FILES['picture']['name'])){
            $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';
            $config['file_name'] = $_FILES['picture']['name'];

            //Load upload library and initialize configuration
            $this->load->library('upload',$config);
            $this->upload->initialize($config);

            if($this->upload->do_upload('picture')){
                $uploadData = $this->upload->data();
                $picture = $uploadData['file_name'];
            }else{
                $picture = '';
            }
        }else{
            $picture = '';
        }

        //Prepare array of user data
        $data_array=array(
            "name" => $this->input->post("txt_name"),
            "email" => $this->input->post("txt_email"), 
            "password" =>  $this->input->post("txt_password"),
            "phone" =>  $this->input->post("txt_phone"),
            "message" =>  $this->input->post("txt_message"),
            "image" => $picture 

        );

        //Pass user data to model
        $insertUserData = $this->form_model1->insert_into_table($data_array);

        //Storing insertion status message.
        if($insertUserData){
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg', 'User data have been added successfully.');
            redirect('home/dashboard');
        }else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error_msg', 'Some problems occured, please try again.');
        }
    }else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error_msg', 'Some problems occured, please try again.');
    }

}
```

Comment: sir this  code is useful and with this code the image easily inserted in the upload folder but the problem I am facing is the path of the images to store in the database.                  "images" =>  $this->input->post("picture"), I had tried with this additional code but the null value is being passed in the database

Comment: try this : "image" => $picture

Comment: thank you very much, with this last code my whole program runs smoothly with insertion of image names in database and getting those images in the upload folder as well.